# Does fork() duplicate all the memory of the parent?

Tags: c, memory, optimization, concurrency, fork

Suppose I compile and run the textbook example of fork().

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
        pid_t pid;
        pid = fork();

        if (pid == -1)
                return 1;

        if (pid == 0)
                puts("From child process.");
        else
                puts("From parent process.");

        return 0;
}
```

Does the code from both branches of the `if (pid == 0)` statement get at `fork()`? In other words, does the child process contain code meant for the parent that will never be executed by it and vice versa? Or does/can the compiler optimize this?

Comment: Yes it does. But it doesn't matter. The optimisation is in the OS not the compiler. The text segment will be shared by all forked processes. That is, the OS will map the same physical memory for the text segment into each of the forked processes. In fact, even the data is shared until there is a write to a particular data page (ie, Copy On Write).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`fork()` duplicates the entire process. The only difference is in the return value of the `fork()` call itself -- in the parent it returns the child's PID, in the child it returns `0`.

Most operating systems optimize this, using a technique called *copy on write*. Rather than copy all the memory, the child shares the parent's memory. However, all the memory pages are marked copy-on-write, which means that if either process modifies something in a page, it will be copied at that time and the process that modified it will be changed to use the copy (and the COW flag will be turned off for the original page as well).

Refer to the Wikipedia articles on [fork](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(system_call)) and [copy-on-write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) for more information.

Comment: IIRC, fork/exec is very slow on cygwin because Windows doesn't have fast support for the `fork()` part.  I forget the details of what cygwin has to do to emulate Unix semantics.  It's fast on all proper Unix OSes, of course.