# Linux equivalent of Process.Start()

Tags: c++, linux, process

On Windows in C#, I can launch an external program from within my code by calling `Process.Start()`, which starts the process and returns its ID. This is important because I am not forking my own process, and I might have to kill the process later.

I have looked at `exec()`, `fork()` and many other things under Linux in C++ but none of those do quite the same thing. For example, `system()` blocks while the program runs, and `fork()` duplicates my whole process just so I can run another task.

Can someone tell me what the equivalent is?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [replace system() with non-blocking function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838565/replace-system-with-non-blocking-function)

Comment: [See if this is in line with your needs](https://linux.die.net/man/3/posix_spawn)

Comment: isn't `Process.Start` working on linux?

Comment: @user4581301 that looks much more like what i need

Comment: @appleapple not in C++, no :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to start a new process on Linux is by using `fork` and `exec`. This you can wrap in your own `System` class that holds the PID and provides methods to kill the process etc. An example of such a class is `QProcess` from the Qt library.

Note: there's also the [posix_spawn()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/posix_spawn) and (Linux specific) [clone()](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html) functions.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Do I really have to fork, creating a duplicate of my entire multimedia application, in order to run the command "unzip" though?

Comment: @DerfSkren: Unfortunately, there's several decades of software which absolutely relies on this, so yes.

Comment: @DerfSkren Re. duplicating the *entire* application, the situation isn't as bad as you think.  See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32130868/does-fork-duplicate-all-the-memory-of-the-parent/32130919#32130919).

Comment: Also note that there is also vfork, which does the bare minimum to create a copy of your process before you exec something new.

Comment: @Botje It's "Copy On Write" anyway, so for a forked process that goes straight to `exec` there's not much actual copying happening in the kernel at all.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the added information. If it is copy on write though, that will mean that I have to use other mechanisms to report back the child PID or any other information once I have forked. I'm hoping not to have to go down that path.

Comment: @Derf What do you mean? The fact that your child processes memory is COW (with 4K page granularity) after `fork` is transparent to you. It's an OS implementation detail. It changes nothing regarding how you'd handle the PID.

Comment: @JesperJuhl If it's copy on write, then how can I write to any memory in the original process?

Comment: @DerfSkren "If it's copy on write, then how can I write to any memory in the original process?" - When you call `fork()` a copy of your process is conceptual made (the original is not changed) - the copy is COW, meaning that unless something is modified it is not changed and there's no cost. If the copy goes on to call `exec` then the entirety of the copy is replaced with the new process, so nothing ever needed to be copied from the original process, so there's no real cost.

Answer (score 1):

There is no equivalent. This is difference between Windows and Linux (and any other Unix-like system). In Unix-like system, new process is always started using `fork() + exec()`. Higher level C library APIs like `system()` use `fork() + exec()` system calls under the hood, because there is absolutely no other way. But Windows always creates new process from scratch. But you should not be discouraged by the fact that `fork()` creates copy of the current process. In fact it does it in a very specific way, so that actually almost nothing copied until write to memory occurs. And even in this case, only modified memory page is copied. Otherwise, creating new processes on Unix/Linux would be over-expensive (for example, assume a process which consumes 4GB of memory wants to execute some shell command). And in fact, `exec()` does the job which `CreateProcess()` does on Windows - assigns new executable image to process, re-initializes heap and stack.

Comment: Thanks for the more detailed explanation. I may have to use fork in the end, but the comment above about `posix_spawn()` what what I was looking for.

Comment: According to man page that's in fact wrapper around combination of the `fork()` and `execve()`, so basically you still employing them, maybe in a bit more convenient way.

Comment: Yeah from what I read it was created to give a nicer interface but also includes some safety and housekeeping that works better in Posix environments that don't fork as nicely as a modern Linux distro.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @user4581301 for the comment above. `posix_spawn()` was what I was looking for.

Here is the code I ended up using though.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

class ProcessCancelHelper {
 private:
  pid_t process_id_;

 public:
  ProcessCancelHelper()
  : process_id_(0) {}

  int StartProcess(const char* command_buffer) {
    const char* command_argv[4];
    command_argv[0] = "sh";
    command_argv[1] = "-c";
    command_argv[2] = command_buffer;
    command_argv[3] = nullptr;

    process_id_ = fork();
    if (process_id_ == -1) return -1;
    if (process_id_ == 0) {
      execvp(command_argv[0], const_cast<char* const*>(command_argv));
      assert(false && "execvp did not work");
      exit(-1);
    }

    int wait_status;
    if (waitpid(process_id_, &wait_status, 0))
    {
      process_id_ = 0;
      if (WIFEXITED(wait_status)) return (WEXITSTATUS(wait_status));
      return -1;
    }

    process_id_ = 0;
    return -1;
  }

  bool CancelProcess() {
    return (process_id_ != 0 && kill(process_id_, SIGKILL) == 0);
  }
}
```

This works and I have not yet tried switching to using `posix_spawn` instead, but as discussed that is just a wrapper.